# MSSql EXECUTE AS USER WITH COOKIE resulting in a memory leak

Tags: sql, sql-server, memory-leaks

I need to use the command `EXECUTE AS USER WITH COOKIE` many times. After implementation, I was noticed that next calls (same) require more time for execution. To reset time execution helps only restart the SQL Server Service.

I wrote 2 simple tests multiple execution of commands:

- `EXECUTE AS USER WITH COOKIE`
- `EXECUTE AS USER`

Examples:

```
DECLARE @Loops INT SET @Loops = 1 
DECLARE @CPU INT SET @CPU = @@CPU_BUSY
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME SET @StartDate = GETDATE() 

WHILE @Loops <= 3000
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @cookie VARBINARY(8000);
    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'RestrictedLogin' WITH COOKIE INTO @cookie;
    declare @ab varchar(MAX);
    set @ab = convert(varchar(MAX), @cookie, 1);    

    REVERT WITH COOKIE = @cookie;

    SET @Loops = @Loops + 1
END

PRINT 'ISNULL, both non-NULL'  
PRINT 'Total CPU time: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @@CPU_BUSY - @CPU) 
PRINT 'Total milliseconds: ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(ms, @StartDate, GETDATE()))   
PRINT ''
```

and

```
DECLARE @Loops INT SET @Loops = 1 
DECLARE @CPU INT SET @CPU = @@CPU_BUSY
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME SET @StartDate = GETDATE() 

WHILE @Loops <= 3000
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @cookie VARBINARY(8000);
    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'RestrictedLogin';
    set @cookie = convert(varbinary(8000), newid());
    declare @ab varchar(MAX);
    set @ab = convert(varchar(MAX), @cookie, 1); 

    REVERT;

    SET @Loops = @Loops + 1
END

PRINT 'ISNULL, both non-NULL'  
PRINT 'Total CPU time: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @@CPU_BUSY - @CPU) 
PRINT 'Total milliseconds: ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(ms, @StartDate, GETDATE()))   
PRINT ''
```

I noticed that for sqlservr process allocated more memory after each execution of `EXECUTE AS USER WITH COOKIE` command. 
At the same time, sqlservr process's private memory not changed at all, after execution `EXECUTE AS USER`. And this example of code require a fewer time for execution (in some times between 3-100x).

To find the amount of private memory I have used the [Performance Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154(v=ws.11).aspx)

My question is - 
How to correctly use the `EXECUTE AS USER WITH COOKIE` command without memory leaks and degradation time?